# Nether portals don't work with World Portals plugin active

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have Bukkit on my SMP server, and world portal so I can have multiple worlds. The problem is, when I build a nether portal, pig zombies spawn next to it, but when I go in it, it just plays the spiral animation and doesn't teleport. I think it has to do with my server having World Portal installed. (And yes, allow-nether=true in server.properties)

Comment: What other plugins do you have (if any) and what version of CraftBukkit are you running?

Comment: I have CommandSigns, Vault, WelcomeMessage, and WorldEdit. I am running craftbukkit 1.4.7-R1.0

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have no Nether world for your new world. World Portals takes over all portal and other-world generation, so you need to tell the server to make a Nether so that Nether portals will go to it. Basically, you need to follow this sequence of actions:

1. In the command console, type `/wp create`
2. Right click on a sign and type `[your-current-world-name-here]_nether` (e.g. if your world was called 'Myworld' then you would type `Myworld_nether`)
3. When asked for a generator type type `nether`

It should now create a new Nether world, and your Nether portals should work!

Comment: To the editor: It is not caused by having the World Portal plugin installed; when you create a new world it doesn't create the nether worlds along with it (except on a vanilla server, but multiworld works differently there) unless it is done by telling the server a different world name. (So it is done if you use a multiworld plugin for bukkit)